# Print system property name if property not found in property file

Tags: java, properties, jvm

I have 2 property files:

application.properties
config.properties

Both of these fiels contains properties in it.

I am loading properties of these fiels by setting system properties in IBM websphere server.

During application startup all properties in both of these files are loaded  through `ApplicationProperty.java` class.

```
private static Properties applicationProperties = new Properties();

 readPropertyFileOne(...){  
properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesLocationOne));
}

readPropertyFileTwo(...){  
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesLocationTwo));
}
```

Now after application starts and read all properties in both files. If I tried to access any property in file through this code

```
findNonNullableProperty(String aPropertyName){
        String value = properties.getProperty(aPropertyName);
        if(value == null){
        //print system property name here. Name can be propertiesLocationOne or propertiesLocationTwo. But what is that? I want to know file location.
        }
    }
```

and it return null.

Comment: your question isn't clear to me. What exactly is app.property? A property file? A system property? Where is properties defined and where is it initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: after evaluating your question again I understand this: You want to get a property value form your own property class. If the property value returns null you want to know which property file holds the key and print out the name of the property file.

The answer to this is that you can't do this. If you read the javadoc for the properties class, you fine that the get("KEY_NAME") method return null only if put an unknown key in. For a empty value you get "", an empty string. As the key is not known it can't be in either of your files. You can't decide which file name to print (or you have to print both).

If you want to do this for the empty strings ("") you have to add more information in your own property class. The java.util.Properties  class uses a hash map to store the key value pairs. After loading the pairs from the file the name of the file isn't available any longer. So you needs to store the file name somewhere.

Next problem is that you load keys from two files into one hash map. Once inside the table you can't decide from which file they where read. Two possible solutions:

1. you add the file name to the key: if you do this in the property file itself it's easy, but you then have to know the file name to get the value.
2. you hold one property for each file: then you have to look into both properties when someone ask fro a value. However this can be wrapped in your Property class, so the user don't know this.

Answer (score 0):

Just get property from System class:

```
public class PrintPropery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("app.property"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is done while starting application. I want to know "app.property" after the application starts and working. Java.util.Properties class does not give much information to get the name of "app.property".

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I know the question exactly. Could you explain more about it ?

Comment: @qrtt1 It's not clear here what you want to achieve. Do you want to retrieve that values of a set of property keys and print them in a file or you want to check the values of a set of property keys.

Comment: I want to print file name if getProperty returns null.